# How can I pass parameters to databricks.yml in Databricks Asset Bundles?

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-pipelines-yaml, databricks-asset-bundle

Background:
I have a separate Databricks Workspace for each environment, and I am buidling an Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy a Databricks Asset Bundles to these environments.

Question
The asset bundle is configured in a databricks.yml file. How do I pass parameters to this file so I can change variables depending on the environment?

For example, I want to be able to vary my scheduling such that it runs more often in Prod than in the lower level environments. In the code below I want to pass {cronExpression} to the file from the pipeline.

Example from `databricks.yml`:

```
bundle:
  name: bundle_name

resources:
  jobs:
    job_name:
      name: job_name
      schedule:
        quartz_cron_expression: {inputParameter}
      tasks:
        ...
```

I have looked at Custom Variables, but it seems they need to be hard-coded in `databricks.yml`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/bundles/settings#--custom-variables

Answer (score 1):

> In the code below I want to pass {cronExpression} to the file from the pipeline.

In DevOps pipeline, you can use `replacetokens@5` to dynamically set the value in file.

For example, have the databricks.yml below, notice the `#{inputParameter}#` format as it will be evaluated in task.

[image]

In DevOps, install extension [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens), add task as below：

I add the variable `inputParameter` i want to use.

[image]

I output the yml file for confirmation:

[image]

Comment: Very cool! I did not know that!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods of passing a value of a variable - it's all described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/bundles/settings#--custom-variables):

- specify it at the top-level of the `databricks.yaml` - then it will be the same for all environments (if they don't override it).
- you can override them for each environment/target separately
- you can pass them via environment variables with names like `BUNDLE_VAR_<variable_name>`
- pass them via command-line: `--var="<var-name>=<var-value>"`

But anyway you need to declare that variable before use - otherwise, the `bundle validate` command won't be able to resolve it & perform validation.

If you want to do that from the Azure DevOps, then the last method could be the best, or maybe environment variables.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using environment variables in my Azure Pipeline, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @KimJensen, glad to know it's resolved. It's recommended to [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work, thanks.

Comment: @alexOtt: Do you know if var-file option would be supported in DABs similar to DBX? That was very helpful- to have the variables segregated out in separate files per environment. And then I could do, dbx deploy -var-file filename, . Something similar would be great in DBX, as it keeps the var declaration separate.